# What will happen if I will purchase a plane tickets being under 18?

Tags: air-travel, uk, tickets

so I want to travel to London to see an event. I need to buy plane tickets, but the problem is I'm not 18 yet. At the tickets purchasing website there's a statement that says I need to be 18.

I could send my money to my parents bank and let them purchase it for me but in my opinion it doesn't really matter. Either way they cannot see my age when I purchase something and even if my parents buy it I still could get in trouble in airport since I'm 16.

So I think there's no point in sending money to parents since it will do nothing. So the whole 18 years requirement seems useless to me. Can you guys state your opinions, cause I really need this sorted out soon.

Comment: The purchasing transaction is distinct from using the ticket and likely has a quite different agreement. The company and their lawyers have different concerns in each case. For the purchase they want to make sure they get paid and that it cannot be reversed (say because a minor cannot be held to a legally binding contract under some conditions- maybe you claim you didn't understand the agreement or whatever).

Comment: They care about getting paid for the ticket. So they require that an adult pay them and enter into the purchase agreement. They may not care that an unaccompanied minor flies on that ticket- check the airline terms and conditions regarding unaccompanied minors. For example, Ryanair's website says 16 is the minimum age. So to do this properly, confirm that you can fly, get your parents to buy the ticket, go and have fun (optional).

Comment: I expect the answer is, no one will notice, the airline will happily take your money.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany your comments, both +1 from me, are really an answer; why don't you go ahead and add them?

Comment: But what's your _question_? This just looks like a rant.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : Agreeing with Dorothy, making an answer would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

I basically agree with [Sheik Paul of Osawatomie](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/56513/sheik-paul-of-osawatomie)'s [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92805/19400), but I would tailor the response more closely to the question.  Therefore:

> I could send my money to my parents bank and let them purchase it for me but in my opinion it doesn't really matter. Either way they cannot see my age when I purchase something

As others have mentioned, the point of the age restriction has to do with the legalities of the financial transaction and, probably, the contract created between the purchaser and the seller.  It does not mean that people under 18 are restricted from *traveling,* only that they are restricted from *buying tickets.*

> and even if my parents buy it I still could get in trouble in airport since I'm 16.

If your parents buy the ticket, you can't get in trouble for buying the ticket.  It is not forbidden to purchase a ticket for someone else, and if your parents have bought the ticket there's no trouble for anyone to get into.

The age restriction does not apply to travelers; it applies to purchasers.

> So I think there's no point in sending money to parents since it will do nothing. So the whole 18 years requirement seems useless to me.

As outlined above, having your parents buy the tickets is precisely what you should do.  The fact that those under 18 have a limited ability to enter into legal agreements may be useless, but the line must be drawn somewhere, and that's where it has been drawn at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the USA, you can have your parents buy you a ticket as an unaccompanied minor.

Although each airline is likely to have their own policy regarding how old you have to be, if there is a surcharge or not, special accommodations, etc.

This is likely the only technically legal way to fly to London (assuming from the USA) without a parent or other adult.

In reality I am not sure if the airlines would care about your age, but there is always the possibility of an ID check when you check bags or go through security which could raise questions.

Comment: Why assume the poster is in the USA?

Comment: @Calchas I did not assume they were from the USA, I simply offered an answer that works if they are. "If you are in the USA", this answer is meant to be helpful if OP is from the USA. If they are not they can disregard it!

Comment: In fact, travelling as an unaccompanied minor isn't just a USA thing, so "If you are in the USA" is probably unnecessary.

Comment: For some, this would be correct, but Petras is too old for the service.  For example, United does not offer it to 16- and 17-year-olds.  Anyway, given his ability to post this question and consider paying for his own ticket, he is probably more than capable of traveling by himself, in which case the service would probably be superfluous and a waste of money.

Comment: @phoog I think the age depends on the airline for sure! But I agree, I think he is more than capable. He just seemed to be concerned with the legal aspect so I thought I would chime in :)

Answer (score -3):

> What will happen if I will purchase a plane tickets being under 18?

If you mislead the airline and purchase the ticket yourself by claiming you're an adult, most likely nothing will happen. The airline **may** cancel the ticket though if they find out. See [these somewhat similar examples](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/penalties-for-underage-user-fraud--1402750.html) for a 17 year old who opened accounts with Paypal, eBay, Amazon, Aliexpress.com that require you to be 18 and over.

> So I think there's no point in sending money to parents since it will
>   do nothing. So the whole 18 years requirement seems useless to me.

That's not correct. Letting your parents purchase it removes that small probability of the airline voiding a contract they entered into with a minor, had you done the purchasing directly.

The issue is one about a financial transaction with a minor. A contract with a minor is voidable, basically you the minor can cancel it any time before execution.

[VOIDABLE CONTRACT](http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/void-vs-voidable-contract-lawyers.html)

> A **voidable** contract is a valid contract and can
>   be enforced. Usually only one party is bound to the contract terms in
>   a voidable contract. The unbound party is allowed to cancel the
>   contract, which makes the contract void.

Basically up until any time the plane takes off, you (because you are the unbound party) can just tell the airline, *I don't want to fly any more, give me my money back*. And because you were a minor, you would be entitled to getting your money back. **The airline doesn't want that kind of uncertainty**.

So coming to it, the issue is not one about you flying as an unaccompanied minor. Many airlines allow children over 12 to fly as unaccompanied minors. In fact I just purchased a ticket last week for my 13 year old nephew to fly unaccompanied all the way to Africa.

Thus sending the money to your parents for them to purchase is materially and legally different from you doing the purchasing. If your parents purchase the ticket, the contract is binding and no longer voidable just because you're a minor.

Comment: That looks like a very US-centric view of things.  Do we have any idea where the OP is based?

Comment: @MadHatter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_in_English_law. It is not just US centric. It is the same in most parts of the world. I cannot say ALL parts of the world, however I can say most.

Comment: Hmmm.  From that article: "*Minors are legally bound where a contract supplies them with [...] services which are deemed [...] beneficial to them. This obligation is codified in the Sale of Goods Act 1979, in section 3*".  So looks like the purchase of a plane ticket, for example, *would* be binding in England and Wales.  I repeat my earlier observation.

Comment: @MadHatter  It can easily be argued that a plane ticket for vacation is not an **essential item for living**.You may need to brush up on the legal requirements. *Contracts for necessaries are for such things as the supply of food, medicines, accommodation and clothing, but generally speaking conveniences and products and services for comfort or pleasure are excluded, as are commercial or trading contracts. These latter contracts are therefore voidable at the option of the minor*. http://www.gillhams.com/site/library/legal_articles/minors_and_contractual_agreements.html.

Comment: The article refers to *goods and services which are deemed necessary **or** beneficial to them*.  A plane ticket may well not be a necessity of life, but it is most definitely a benefit.  Note also that s3 Sale of Goods Act 1979 makes exactly the same voidability provisions for people who are incapable by reason of drunkenness, and no airline I know requires a breath test before booking a ticket.  In short, airlines may well refuse to sell tickets to persons under 18, but I do not think that this is the reason why.

Comment: @MadHatter Not only do I believe you are wrong, but also the answer was a general answer and like I wrote it is applicable in the majority of countries around the world. For example under European law per the European Consumer Center, generally *Young people between seven to 14 or 14 to 18 years have limited contractual capacity. However, the guardians have the option to approve or cancel a contract **in retrospect**. Only **small businesses**, which don't harm the livelihood of young people, can be done independently*. The average airline ticket  will not fall under **small business**

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes, the minor gets a flight, but he also has to pay money. So you cannot just claim that the contract is beneficial.

Comment: @gnasher729 sorry, what?  The law refers to contracts for goods and services which are beneficial, that is, of benefit to the contracting party.  It doesn't mean they're free.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie you're missing my second point.  Even if minors can void a contract for an airplane ticket (and I don't think it's clear that they can, but I can definitely see your argument), the law gives the same protection to persons incapable by reason of drunkenness (or more precisely, recognises their comparable inability to enter into contracts), and airlines *definitely* don't refuse to sell people tickets by virtue of their BAC.  So even if airlines refuse to sell tickets to under-18s, this is probably not the reason why.

Comment: This doesn't really answer OPs question - does the airline really care who's making the purchase or do they simply use legalese to avoid any issues? Practically speaking - can OP just pay and fly?

Comment: The question is "what will happen if I try to buy the ticket", not "can I have a first year lecture in contract law please?" Also, it doesn't explain why the airline can't sell the minor a full flex ticket, they love selling those to me. :)